# where is " <groupId>org.glassfish.embedded</groupId>" repository here?

Tags: java, maven-2, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I want to use `<groupId>org.glassfish.embedded</groupId>` in my dependencies. What repository should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you want to use but the groupId `org.glassfish.embedded` looks pretty old.

I suggest to check the more recent [maven coordinates](https://glassfish.dev.java.net/downloads/3.0.1-final.html#maven) that have been published with the release of GlassFish 3.0.1 and to use the Nexus repository for GlassFish:

```
<repository>
   <id>java.net</id>
   <name>GlassFish Maven Repository</name>
   <url>http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: You're welcome. This repository is mentioned in the link I posted in my answer: https://glassfish.dev.java.net/downloads/3.0.1-final.html#maven

Answer (score 1):

Since version 3.1.2, glassfish artifacts are in Maven Central, so you don't need any special repository.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish/org/glassfish/embedded/ ?

Add the respository to your pom.xml

```
<repository>
<id>glassfish.java.net</id>
<name>Glassfish repository</name>
<url>http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish</url>
<layout>legacy</layout>
</repository>
```

What artifact do  you want though?

Comment: Use this repository but warning message

Unable to update index for maven2-repository.dev.java.net|http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish/: Resource nexus-maven-repository-index.properties does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help: From [What is the official Maven repository for Embedded GlassFish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686615/what-is-the-official-maven-repository-for-embedded-glassfish) : http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish/org/glassfish/extras/glassfish-embedded-all/3.1.1/