# Maven cannot download Glassfish embedded package

Tags: maven, glassfish

I have a problem with maven. I wanted to add dependency to embedded Glassfish. I added an entry to pom.xml, containing a fragment copied from internet:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

However, mvn package prints an error.

```
Access denied to: http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/glassfish/extras/glassfish-embedded-all/3.1/glassfish-embedded-all-3.1.pom -> [Help 1]
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Did you pointed to the right repository at you pom.xml file?

Insert this at the end of it, just before the last `</project>` tag:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>glassfish-releases</id>
    <url>http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to http://repository.jboss.org/maven2 per HTTP throws an 403 Forbidden error, as it is outdated.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116978/where-is-groupidorg-glassfish-embedded-groupid-repository-here) has:

```
http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish
```

as the new URL.