# What is the official Maven repository for Embedded GlassFish?

Tags: maven, glassfish-embedded

http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish/ looks like it should be GlassFish's official Maven repository, but it currently hosts only up to version 3.1.1-b05 of glassfish-embedded-all (see http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish/org/glassfish/extras/glassfish-embedded-all/).

http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish/org/glassfish/extras/ is linked to from Embedded GlassFish's site (Embedded Jars). It doesn't look like an official Maven repository but hosts up to 3.1.1-b11 (at http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish/org/glassfish/extras/glassfish-embedded-all/).

So the question is which would be the reliable repository to get the Maven dependencies for Embedded GlassFish from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest (3.1.2) I could find was at 
https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/org/glassfish/main/extras/glassfish-embedded-all/

Unfortunately, for 3.1.2.2 as of August 21, 2012 seems to be nowhere!

I've just opened an issue:
http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-19028
The very strange thing is that while opening the issue I saw the 3.1.2.2 still classified as "Unreleased Version"...

**UPDATE!**
Today glassfish staff answered :
3.1.2.2 maven artifacts are not yet available on maven central / maven.java.net release repo.
You can find them here: 
https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/org/glassfish/main/extras/glassfish-embedded-all/3.1.2.2/

Comment: Any idea where the source code is available?  The glassfish-embedded-all-3.1.2.2-sources.jar available at these sites is about 2k and is basically empty.

Answer (score 2):

As of August 3, 2011 at 12:43 PM EDT http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish/org/glassfish/extras/glassfish-embedded-all/3.1.1 should get you what you want.  This is the correct repository.

Comment: Latest release candidates and milestone don't seem to be hosted here anymore. They're not in https://maven.java.net either - java.net's official maven repository.

Comment: For reasons that I've never been clear on, the embedded Glassfish stuff tends to trail the main distribution by several revisions.  You can see all revisions here: http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish/org/glassfish/extras/glassfish-embedded-all/